# Expose publicly Kubernetes service using deployment and LoadBalancer service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When creating a simple hello-world deployment via a declarative yaml manifest, and a LoadBalancer typed service to expose it, everything is created successfully however when hitting the external IP of the service it is unreachable.

Here is the yaml file I'm using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-test
  labels:
    app: my-test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8888
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  # - port: 443
  #   targetPort: 8888
  #   protocol: TCP
  #   name: https
  selector:
    app: my-test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-test
  labels:
    app: my-test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-test
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello- app:2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
```

I've figured out that If I create the deployment using a run command I can create the service either via yaml or kubectl expose command. I am new to K8s so not sure what is wrong with the deployment declaration.

Using the following commands it works fine

```
kubectl run hello-server --image gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 --port 8080
```

Then I ran the following command to expose the deployment:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-server --type LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide output of `kubectl describe svc hello-server`

Comment: You have a space in the container image value.

Comment: Is your cluster is declared as `private_cluster=false`? and `http_load_balancing.disabled=false`

Comment: Name:                     hello-server
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=hello-server
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=hello-server
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.39.254.175
LoadBalancer Ingress:     35.197.106.206
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32632/TCP
Endpoints:                10.36.2.13:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Comment: also here is the output of svc my-test Name:                     my-test
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=my-test
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"my-test"},"name":"my-test","namespace":"default"},"spec"...
Selector:                 app=my-test
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.39.248.194
LoadBalancer Ingress:     35.199.153.196
Port:                     http  80/TCP

Comment: TargetPort:               8888/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32550/TCP
Endpoints:                10.36.0.15:8888,10.36.1.12:8888,10.36.2.18:8888
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Comment: Here is the cluster definition Name 
default-pool
Size
3
Node version 
1.9.7-gke.11 Upgrade available
Node image 
Container-Optimized OS (cos) Change
Machine type 
g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)
Total cores 
3 vCPUs
Total memory 
5.10 GB
Automatic node upgrades 
Enabled
Next auto-upgrade 
Not scheduled
Automatic node repair 
Enabled
Autoscaling 
Off
Preemptible nodes 
Disabled
Boot disk type 
Standard persistent disk
Boot disk size in GB (per node) 
100

Comment: The space in the image name must have been added when I copied the yaml here, in the actual file there is no space in the image, also the deployment was created successfully...

Comment: Please add that to the question. It's very unreadable.